# Extends myapp base.html - not from other app in my django project

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I wrote a Django project which includes some apps. I made a base.html in my users app but I will use of the base.html from my articles app.
I used `{% extends 'base.html' %}` in general and I tried:

```
{% extends 'articles:base.html' %} or {% extends 'articles/base.html' %}
```

and in myproject/settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    ...
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    ...
]
```

but they did not work.

I would be glad if someone help me.

Answer (score 3):

If your template is located `users/templates/base.html`, then you would use `{% extends 'base.html' %}`. However Django's app template loader stops as soon as it finds a match, so will use `users/templates/base.html` if `users` is above `articles` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

For that reason, Django recommends that you create subdirectories inside the app's templates directory. Then save your templates as `users/templates/users/base.html` and `articles/templates/articles/base.html`. Now, you can use `{% extends 'articles/base.html' %}` and `{% extends 'users/base.html' %}`, and your template names won't clash with each other.